# not able to open registration form page

Tags: python, django

trying to create a registration form, and  I am facing an issue. so, below are my python pages:

### form.py

```
from .models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm

class SignUpForm(ModelForm):
   class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password','email')
```

### models.py

```
from django.db import models
#from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Registration(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

### urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
  url(r'^register/$', views.SignUpFormView, name= 'register'),
]
```

### test.html

```
{% extends 'user_info/base.html' %}
{% block body %}
{% block content %}

<form method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
  username:<br>
  <input type="text" name="username"><br>
  password:<br>
  <input type="text" name="password"><br>
  email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><br>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

### views.py

```
def SignUpFormView(request):
    template_name = 'test.html'
    try:
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
                password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
                email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
                return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})
    except ValueError:
        print("Oops!  That was not a valid entry, try again...")

    else:
        SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'user_info/about.html')
```

The issue is, my "SignUpFormView" function in views.py is not entering the "if" statement, its directly going to "else". I seem to be lost here.
I have 'about.html'. I do not see any error as well. Which I find very weird. Please help.

Note: I am using Django's default in-built "User" model, and I do not wish to create any custom model.

### Modified views.py

```
def SignUpFormView(request):
    user_form = 'SignUpForm'
    template_name = 'test.html'

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = user_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            #username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            #password = form.cleaned_data.get('password')
            #email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            #user.save()
            return render(request, template_name, {'form':form})


    else:
        SignUpForm()

    return render(request, 'user_info/about.html')
```

### Modified forms.py

```
from .models import User
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm



class SignUpForm(forms.ModelForm):
    #password = forms.Charfield(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
       model = User
       fields = ('username','password','email')
```

### modified test.html

```
{% extends 'user_info/base.html' %}


{% block body %}
{% block content %}


{% for error in form.errors %}
    {{ form.errors | default_errors }}
{% endfor %}

<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    {% for field in form %}
        <p>

      username:<br>
      <input type="text" name="username"><br>
      password:<br>
      <input type="text" name="password"><br>
      email:<br>
      <input type="text" name="email"><br>
      {% for error in field.errors %}
           <p style="color: red">{{ error }}</p>
    {% endfor %}
        </p>
    {% endfor %}
    <button type="submit" value="Submit">sign up </button>
</form>


{% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You've got a lot of pointless code there. What's the point of those definitions of username, password and email in the is_valid block? You never use them. You don't need the try/except statements either, since that is all done by the form. And finally you are never passing the invalid form to the template, or showing the contents of `form.errors`, so the user will never see why the validation failed.

Comment: @Daniel, can you plz give me an example of "passing the invalid form to the template", or guide me to a link

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/forms/#the-view

Comment: Okay, I made the changes suggested by you, still, I do not see any change in the app behavior. I have edited the original post with modified codes. Please suggest/correct me further